# "Select All" from Contacts in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

In WhasApp, is there any button for "Select All" from Contacts; in order that one single message goes to all?

Answer (score 1):

Well, nope there isn't any select all option available over the WhatsApp, rather than it has the feature called Broadcast messages !

To Broadcast the message:

> - Open up WhatsApp.
> - Tap over the three dots available on top right side of the screen.
> - Now Select the option "BroadCast Message".
> - Tap over the + button to add recipient name over the Broadcast list.
> - Next thing to do is tap over the continue button.

Like, the above user said that, presently it has a limit of 256 broadcast limit.

You can also refer to the [WhatsApp Support Section](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23130793) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Select All" when sending a [WhatsApp Broadcast Message](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23130793). Presently there is a limit of sending 256 people a broadcast message.

Comment: from which soure/reference, this limit of 256 you found? I did not see this limit described in the link that you gave while Answering! You may want to remove that if there is no "official" source or put the reference to that official sourece

Comment: ^^ If you try sending a broadcast message, the counter on the top counts the people with a limit of 256 eg. 1/256, 2/256 and so on. Try sending one now and you'll see it. @MeTechnical